# UITableView beginUpdates/endUpdates callback

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, animation

I'm making changes to a tableView using a beginUpdates/endUpdates block. Throughout the way I need to update a drop shadow so that it reflects the tableView's current composition.

I tried setting up KVO for the tableView's `contentSize` but it's only called on `endUpdates`, once the animation has finished. What I want is for it to be called every time `contentSize` changes (even if it's by only a pixel). Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to say, I don't think you can do this. When you make changes to the table in after `beginUpdates` has been called the changes are animated as a single animation after `endUpdates`. There are no animation callbacks during these animations. I haven't tried this so don't know if it would work well for this but you could try nesting `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` and updating your shadow after each `endUpdates`.

Comment: Just FYI: Invocations of beginUpdates and endUpdates can be nested. If you do not make the insertion, deletion, and selection calls inside this block, table attributes such as row count might become invalid.

Comment: Have you an example of how nested calls should be used?

Answer (score 24):

What about this?

```
[CATransaction begin];

[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    // animation has finished
}];

[tableView beginUpdates];
// do some work
[tableView endUpdates];

[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: wow! that almost works but there is a delay between the tableview ending the updates and the completion block running. For now I will use that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Rudolf's method did not work for me as smooth as expected. In my case I was selecting a row on `UITableView` using this, and Rudolf's method was causing the table to do two animations with a little freeze: the animation inside beginUpdates/endUpdates, a little freeze and the animation on the completion block.

```
 [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                        animated:YES
                  scrollPosition:scrollPosition];
```

that inspired me to create this code... and this is working seamlessly:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 animations:^{
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    // do something to the table
    [tableView endUpdates];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // Code to run when table updates are complete.
}];
```